# Using functions in dplyr incorporating values in other rows

Tags: r, dplyr

Apologies in advance for the clunky code. 
I have a data frame similar to the following:

```
df <- data.frame(c(rep_len(1,5), 2, 2), c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"))
names(df) <- c("id", "consequence")

  id consequence
1  1           A
2  1           A
3  1           B
4  1           B
5  1           C
6  2           C
7  2           C
```

I would like to perform the following filtering action:

> if a group by id contains consequences A or B, then keep these rows, and remove rows with consequence C. If a group contains only C, or a single row, then keep those/that rows/row.

I have tried to do this in dplyr with a custom function, but have the problem that all the rows are filtered, thus eliminating all of consequence C:

```
# filtering function:
consequence_select <- function(x) {
  if(n_distinct(x$consequence) > 1) {
  if(any(unique(x$consequence) %in% c("A", "B"))) {
  x %>%
    filter(consequence %in% c("A", "B"))} else {return(x)}
     } else {return(x)}
}


df %>%
group_by(id) %>%
consequence_select

  id consequence
1  1           A
2  1           A
3  1           B
4  1           B
```

I was able to do this correctly with plyr:

```
ddply(df, .(id), consequence_select)

  id consequence
1  1           A
2  1           A
3  1           B
4  1           B
5  2           C
6  2           C
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `dplyr` you need to wrap the function in `do`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  do(consequence_select(.))
```

The `.` is a "pronoun" that refers to the data frame `df`.

Answer (score 4):

You could optimize your code by applying it only inside a `filter` argument and not inside a `do` as `filter` is the specialized dplyr function for such a task. I created two functions and benchmarked them with the existing answers. Which function you want to use depends on your requirements - for the sample data, they both produce the same result. I also created a slightly larger sample data for the benchmark, as below.

```
# sample data
df <- data.frame(id = sample(100, 1000, replace = T), 
                 consequence = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 1000, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.6)))

# the existing custom function
consequence_select <- function(x) {
  if(n_distinct(x$consequence) > 1) {
    if(any(unique(x$consequence) %in% c("A", "B"))) {
      x %>%
        filter(consequence %in% c("A", "B"))} else {return(x)}
  } else {return(x)}
}

# eipi's answer
f1 <- function() {
  df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  do(consequence_select(.)) }

# jazzuro's answer
f2 <- function() {
  df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  do(if(all(.$consequence == "C")) {.} else{.[-which(.$consequence == "C"), ]}) }

# my answer 1
f3a <- function() {
  df %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    filter((consequence != "C" & n_distinct(consequence) > 1L) | all(consequence == "C") )
}

# my answer 2
f3b <- function() {
  df %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    filter((consequence %in% c("A", "B") & n_distinct(consequence) > 1L) | all(consequence == "C"))
}

library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(f1(), f2(), f3a(), f3b(), unit = "relative")

Unit: relative
 expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
f1()  11.243524 11.092915 10.956129 10.717519  8.859949   100
f2()   6.603549  6.663674  6.653424  6.566012 10.956784   100
f3a()  1.279952  1.294679  1.291719  1.294606  1.165322   100
f3b()  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000   100

all.equal(f1(), f3a())
#[1] TRUE
all.equal(f1(), f3b())
#[1] TRUE
```

As you can see, a slight increase in data size already reveals a >10 times speed difference between the functions.

Comment: Good to see this. Thank you. I expected `do` would be slower.

Comment: I just started thinking now. But, would it be better to avoid `do` and create your own function like this? I was wondering this conditional filtering issue the other day. If you can do filter(if(...){} else{}), that is sweet. But this is not possible as far as I know. Then, my answer was do. Seeing what you suggested, writing one's own function facilitates his/her data processing more.

Comment: @jazzurro - I don't really understand your comments. Regarding the first one: don't you think 6-10 time slower is already a significant difference? And for the second: "Seeing what you suggested, writing one's own function facilitates his/her data processing more." I don't follow. "If you can do filter(if(...){} else{})": in a filter you only need TRUE / FALSE, so you really only need to make the logical test which would be in the if(...) the rest should not be needed.

Comment: Yes, 6-10 times is such a huge difference. As for the 2nd comment, I had a dummy example I was working on. Would you help me? `do(if(length(.$value) > 1 & is.na(.$value[1])) {.[-1,]} else{.})` is the one I have. You use `group_by` and try to remove the first row from each group if each group has more than 2 rows and if the first row has NA. How would you write this `do` line using `filter`? Not having computer science background at all, I am hoping my writing makes sense to you somewhat.

Comment: @jazzurro, based on your verbal description, I would use: `df %>% group_by(var1) %>% filter((!is.na(var2) & n() != 1) | row_number() > 1L)` - you can check if that's correct since there's no reproducible example here.. (btw, I don't have a computer science background either). This would be better suited as a separate question ..

Comment: Sorry for this late reply. Thank you very much for your suggestion. I will try and see how this works with my practice sample. I have not used `filter` in this way before. I need to learn how to write logical statement like this. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do your function like this using `do`. `foo` is your data.

```
foo %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    do(if(all(.$consequence == "C")) {.} else{.[-which(.$consequence == "C"), ]})

#  id consequence
#1  1           A
#2  1           A
#3  1           B
#4  1           B
#5  2           C
#6  2           C
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice simplification of the conditional as well.

Comment: @gatsky Pleasure, mate. :-)